Why GDB Debugger Lacks Echo, Requires Double Enter, or Fails to Interact with Target Program?
I just started debugging with gdb (never used before)
A simple program:
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    char str[100];
    printf("Enter a string: ");
    scanf("%s", str);
    printf("You entered: %s", str);
}

Run:
PS D:\start_video\c> gcc -g temp.c -o temp
PS D:\start_video\c> gdb .\temp.exe
GNU gdb (GDB) (Cygwin 13.2-1) 13.2
Copyright (C) 2023 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Type "show copying" and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-pc-cygwin".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
    <http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.

For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from .\temp.exe...
(gdb) l
warning: Source file is more recent than executable.
1       #include <stdio.h>
2
3       void main()
4       {
5           char str[100];
6           printf("Enter a string: ");
7           scanf("%s", str);
8           printf("You entered: %s", str);
9       }
(gdb) run
Starting program: /cygdrive/d/start_video/c/.\temp.exe
[New Thread 14552.0x3b5c]
Enter a string: You entered: nsrfcs[Thread 14552.0x3b5c exited with code 19]

Program terminated with signal SIGCONT, Continued.
The program no longer exists.
(gdb)

I tried to change the code, and a bigger problem came up!
This connection cannot be entered at all! I tried to type on the keyboard
There's no response!
Wait a while and then appear:
[Thread 3628.0x4644 exited with code 0]
why????
Is this my problem or gdb's problem?
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char str[100];
    printf("Enter a string: ");
    fgets(str, sizeof(str), stdin);
    str[strcspn(str, "\n")] = 0; 
    printf("You entered: %s\n", str);
    return 0;
}

PS D:\start_video\c> gcc -g temp.c -o temp
PS D:\start_video\c> gdb .\temp.exe
GNU gdb (GDB) (Cygwin 13.2-1) 13.2
Copyright (C) 2023 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Type "show copying" and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-pc-cygwin".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
    <http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.

For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from .\temp.exe...
(gdb) run
Starting program: /cygdrive/d/start_video/c/.\temp.exe
[New Thread 17252.0x11d8]
qn trjry tring: You entered: sagagg
[Thread 17252.0x11d8 exited with code 0]
[Inferior 1 (process 17252) exited normally]
(gdb) run
Starting program: /cygdrive/d/start_video/c/.\temp.exe
[New Thread 9856.0x3f08]
Enter a string: [Thread 9856.0x3f08 exited with code 0]



You may need to call fflush(stdout); between the calls to printf and fgets.

You're using a cygwin gdb. Is your target application also compiled for cygwin? Does the problem also happen in the cygwin terminal?

From your examples, you seem to be compiling the program as "PS D:\start_video\c> gcc -g temp.c -o temp", yet running gdb as "PS D:\start_video\c> gdb .\temp.exe".  Note  that the output from the compilation is just 'temp' (unless cygwin automatically adds an 'exe' extension - I don't know I don't use cygwin).  Try running gdb as 'gdb .\temp'.  Notice that in your first example you got the warning "warning: Source file is more recent than executable."   That leads me to wonder what your were actually debugging.

The observation from @thurizas would also explain why gdb warns you "warning: Source file is more recent than executable." You might have an old binary in your directory, which you run in the debugger, while the application you compiled has a different name.

@thurizas,cywin was an exe extension that was added, and as to what I was actually debugging, at this point in time, I also forget, except that I solved that problem in some other non-debugging way, right

@[Ian Abbott] I just tried this solution, but it didn't work

@Joachim 我确定没有旧的二进制文件,出现"warning: Source file is more recent than executable."的原因可能是我调试时,在VScode上不小心按了回车或者正在将scanf替换为fgets
